# Unable to insert values into bytea type attribute while migrating from postgres 7.4 to postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am migrating an application from postgres 7.4 to postgres 9.2. The query which worked fine for inserting bytea type attribure values in postgres 7.4 is throwing PSQLException with the below error in postgres 9.2.

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...07\000\000\001\002\000\000|\012\000\000\'\007\000...(Error is shown near the single quote)

*** *Error* *****

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 39081

I have read the postgres documentation about bytea_output which can be set to 'escape' to output the content of the attribute in escape format. It is also mentioned that bytea type attributes can accept both escape and hex format.

As the application was previously using postgres 7.4, we are using escape format. I wonder why this error is thrown if bytea can accept both escape and hex format in postgres 9.2. Please help in resolving this error.

Comment: Are you using the 9.2 JDBC driver?

Comment: I executed the query from pgAdmin and got the above mentioned error.

Comment: Please show us the full query. And did you verify that the pgAdmin version is the right one to work with Postgres 9.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytea_output` tells the format of bytea content in output columns, not when submitted as part of a SQL statement. As you guessed, it's probably not relevant here.

However, what may be relevant is the fact `standard_conforming_strings` has been set ON by default with PG 9.1 (I don't think it even existed in 7.4) so you can no longer use backslash to escape a single quote inside a literal.

See the compatibility flags and explanations in 9.2 doc: [Previous PostgreSQL Versions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-COMPATIBLE-VERSION), especially `backslash_quote`, `escape_string_warning` and `standard_conforming_strings`.

Short of fixing your app, the easy way out of the problem is to set `standard_conforming_strings` to off, and `escape_string_warning` to off if the amount of warnings in the logs is problematic (actually this warning is mostly useful in the process of fixing your app to standard strings conformance).

This can be done globally in the `postgresql.conf` file, which is located in the data directory. See [Setting Parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/config-setting.html) in the doc.

```
standard_conforming_strings=off  
escape_string_warning=off
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you please tell how to set those compatibitiy flags to off.

Comment: I have set 'standard_conforming_strings=off', 'escape_string_warning=off', 'backslash_quote=off' and 'bytea_output=escape' in the postgresql.conf file and restarted the server.
I am still getting the same error when I try to insert values to bytea attributes. Any other workaround for this?

Comment: @user2416545: `backslash_quote=off` is the reason. Note that I suggested to turn off the two others, not this one.

Comment: Same error if I keep backslash_quote=on and backslash_quote=safe-encoding. I am not clear where I am going wrong.

Comment: @user2416545: can you update the question with the error or lack thereof that happens on a simple `select 'ab\'cd'::bytea;`? Also you can double check the values of `standard_conforming_strings` and other settings in the client with `show standard_conforming_strings`.

Comment: I used "show standard_conforming_strings" to get the current status and I set it to off with query "set standard_conforming_strings=off". Now the insert query is working fine. Thank you  Daniel Vérité for your guidance in solving this issue.